# IllegalArgumentException initializing chronicle map

Tags: java, chronicle-map

Here is the piece of code I have

```
MyValue sampleValue = Values.newHeapInstance(MyValue.class); 

// subsequently set the couple of floats and int i have defined in MyValue interface

ChronicleMap<MyKey, MyValue> cache = ChronicleMapBuilder.of(MyKey.class, MyValue.class)
                .entries(100)
                .averageValue(sampleValue)
                .create();
```

When I do this I get the error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Using BytesMarshallable and an
>   interface value type not supported at
>   net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.averageValue(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:660)

Can someone help me understand if this usage pattern is in-correct?

If I change to creating MyValue by implementing a concrete class and then doing a new on that as follows it works:

```
MyValue sampleValue = new MyValueImpl();

// subsequently set the couple of floats and int i have defined in MyValue interface

ChronicleMap<MyKey, MyValue> cache = ChronicleMapBuilder.of(MyKey.class, MyValue.class)
                .entries(100)
                .averageValue(sampleValue)
                .create();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this exception can be found in the [source](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/map/ChronicleMapBuilder.java#L660):

```
            if (Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(valueClass))
                LOG.warn("BytesMarshallable " + valueClass + " will be serialized as Serializable as the value class is an interface");
            else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Using BytesMarshallable and an interface value type not supported");
}
```

Which simply calls the [isAssignableFrom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) method of the class Class which checks:

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object
>   is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the
>   class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter. It
>   returns true if so; otherwise it returns false. If this Class object
>   represents a primitive type, this method returns true if the specified
>   Class parameter is exactly this Class object; otherwise it returns
>   false.

So this checks if the `Serializable` Class is represented by the `valueClass`. So my understanding is that your `MyValue` isn't implementing the `Serializable` interface.

And yeah, even the comment states it:

> Configures the average number of bytes, taken by **serialized** form of
>   values

So If I'm not mistaken, simply let your Value Class implement the [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface and you should be fine. Pretty ... confusing exception message I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `Values.newHeapInstance()` suggests that `MyValue` is a so-called [value interface](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Values#value-interface-specification). Objects of a specific value interface have constant size in serialized form. Value interfaces are supported by ChronicleMap specially, so you shouldn't configure value size at all, as presented in [this example from tutorial](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/master/docs/CM_Tutorial.adoc#value-interfaces-instead-of-boxed-primitives):

```
ChronicleMap<LongValue, Order> orders = ChronicleMap
    .of(LongValue.class, Order.class)
    .name("orders-map")
    .entries(1_000_000)
    .create();

LongValue key = Values.newHeapInstance(LongValue.class);
key.setValue(id);
orders.put(key, order);
```

Note that there is no `averageValue()` call, nor `averageValueSize()`, nor `constantValueSizeBySample()`.

The presented error message is indeed confusing, especially since ChronicleMap already knows that value class is a value interface and knows it's size. Feel free to open an issue in https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map.